# linkedInDistributionTarget is required even though it is empty

Tags: java, spring, rest, linkedin-api

While posting a share, linkedInDistributionTarget is mandatory field which needs to be included in the body of post request. Even though it is empty Why do we need to include in the body.

If i am not using that key,Following error is thrown

```
{
    "owner": "urn:li:organization:xxxxxx",
    "text": {
        "text": "Hii Kaushik from builder"
    }
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.restli.client.RestLiResponseException: Response status 400, serviceErrorMessage: com.linkedin.publishing.util.common.ResponseException: Company owned UGCs can only have PUBLIC or LOGGED_IN MemberNetworkVisibility.",
    "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their docs:

"Omitting distribution.linkedInDistributionTarget during share creation creates a dark or hidden share which is not shown publicly on LinkedIn.com. Specify the field as an empty object to make the share publicly viewable."

Source:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context#post-shares